# Aurelia flux dispatch only call once on activate method

Tags: aurelia

Don't know if anyone has encountered this issue.
I'm using flux to load stuff on the active method on some modules.
Just like this:

```
export class ContractRate{

    constructor(dispatcher){
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    activate() {
        this.dispatcher.dispatch('rates.get');
    }

    @handle('rates.changed')
    ratesChanges(action, rates){
        this.rates = rates;
    }

}


export class Index{
    constructor(dispatcher){
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    @handle('rates.get')
    getRates(){
            //here there's some code that retrieves the rates
            this.dispatcher.dispatch('rates.changed', this.rates);
    }

    @handle('rates.changed')
    ratesChanges(action, rates){
        this.rates = rates;
    }
}
```

The thing is that it seems that the
**this.dispatcher.dispatch('rates.get');**
only occurs once.

**ContractRate** is loaded when a certain tab is selected, that triggers the activate method that starts all the dispatchment of events.
This works the first time the activate method is executed, the next times not.

I'm pretty sure this is happening because I'm using the dispatcher on the activate method, since I've moved the dispatcher call to another method and it works completely fine.

Hope any of you peeps can help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was easy.
If you want to handle events, don't keep the methods that do that on modules that can be deactivated.

In my case, I moved all the handling methods outside of one of my routers and place it in a different module.
As easy as that.